# Is there any built-in convenient mechanism to generate relative URLs?

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5

1- Laravel `url` function generates a fully qualified URL to the given path. I need to generate relative path and only prepend them the site **base url**. I seems unlike other well-known framework it does not have a config to set the base URL. What is the correct way to generate relative paths?

---

2- On the other hand, if, for example, the user requests `http://url/base/user/1/edit` url, how to only get the `user/1/edit` part?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember 
    `$uri = Request::path();` 
or  `$url = $request->path();`
You can try. Hope this help

Comment: you should comment if you are not sure

Comment: @KhanShahrukh Sorry, I'm really want to put a comment but I don't have enough 50 reputation to comment anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You may use URL::to('/'); anywhere in your app to refer to the base url and to get the part of the url you can use :

```
public function someFunction(Request $request)
{
     $firstpart = $request->segment(1);
     $secondpart = $request->segment(2);
     // and so on
}
```